# Display image at the start of TextField material-ui and not to either side?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

How would I display an image inside a TextField as if it was part of the text, like an InputAdornment just not to either side, but at the beginning of the TextField.
[image: An example of what I am trying to accomplish]

and not next as an icon next to the text input area which is what InputAdornment does (e.g., not like a search icon next to a query field)?

Only way I can think of is just placing the image above the TextField but I found this made it not obvious that the image is part of the input.

I've looked through the documentation but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of accomplishing this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you can't. An `<input>` element that is type `text` only accepts text. The solution is to craft a custom element like a `<div>` or `<span>` into which you can place an `<img>` element first followed by an _editor_ element. You can then make the editor element `contentEditable`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments on your question are *partially* correct.  You can't reasonably edit the actual `<input>` without losing functionality, but the `Textfield` component is not *just* an `<input>` and is composed of multiple elements that *can* contain/display an image.

Since no MUI version was specified, I'll assume that you're using latest. (This can also be accomplished with the MUI 4 `TextField` using the old `makeStyles` function.)

You can change the placement of the `TextField` `startAdornment` with a few changes to the underlying CSS. Essentially, you can change the default `flex-direction` from `row` to `column` and then finesse the gutters to your liking:

```
    <TextField
      id="input-with-icon-textfield"
      label="TextField"
      variant="outlined"
      sx={{
        ".MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
          paddingTop: "1rem",
          flexDirection: "column"
        },
        img: {
          paddingRight: "1rem"
        }
      }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x150/200" />
      }}
      placeholder="Enter image caption..."
    />
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/inputwithicon-material-demo-forked-tyx7y?file=/demo.js:139-580

Comment: Yes, this seems like a better approach than mines.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the native input element produced by the library and place a background image on it. You would then define a `background-position-(x|y)` to adjust the image placement. To alter the text position accordingly, you would move the cursor around inside the field by specifying the `padding` or `text-indent` property.

Below background positions `5px 6px` for **x** and **y** placement is set at the end of the `background` property respectively.

```css
input[type='text'][class^='MuiInput'] {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/20/00ff00/000) no-repeat 5px 6px;
  padding-left: 10px; /* or */ text-indent: 10px;
}
```